# jqGrid toolbar search and Django

Tags: jquery, django, search, jqgrid

i'm using jqGrid to add Toolbar Search like the example in the Toolbar Search Example
and already implemented basics and advanced examples like site tutorials and my page is like [this](http://uploadax.com/images/99663522299263074342.png)
but i don't know how to use this feature in Django !!! what's the name of those input types on the top of my grid !??
the example is not clear  ! can you help me ??
[here's my source code on github][4]

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index Page</title>
    <!-- external scripts -->

    <!-- jQuery & Bootstrap -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/jquery.js" %}"/></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" %}"/></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="{% static "css/bootstrap.min.css?id=1" %}"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/bootstrap.min.js" %}"/></script>
    <!-- jQuery & Bootstrap -->

    <!-- jqGrid -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="{% static "css/ui.jqgrid.css" %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="{% static "css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.min.css" %}" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/grid.locale-en.js" %}"/></script>
    <!-- jqGrid -->

    <!-- own implemented scripts -->
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/script.js" %}"/></script>  -->
    <!-- own implemented scripts -->

    <!-- external scripts-->

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#list").jqGrid({
            url: "http://localhost:8000/getdata",
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: "GET",
            colNames: ["id", "name", "english_title", "capacity"],
            colModel: [
            { name: "id", index:"id", width: 55 },
            { name: "name", width: 80 },
            { name: "english_title", width: 130, align: "right" },
            { name: "capacity", width: 80, align: "right" },
            ],
            rowNum:10,
            rowList:[10,20,30],
            pager: '#pager',
            loadonce:true,
            sortname: 'id',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "desc",
            rownumbers: true,
            rownumWidth: 40,
            gridview: true,
            multiselect: false,
            caption: "Rooms",
            onSelectRow: function(ids) {
                if(ids == null) {
                    ids=0;
                    if(jQuery("#list_d").jqGrid('getGridParam','records') >0 )
                    {

                        console.log(ids);
                        jQuery("#list_d").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:"getpricelist?q=1&id="+ids,page:1}).trigger('reloadGrid');

                    }
                } else {
                    console.log(ids);
                    jQuery("#list_d").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:"getpricelist?q=1&id="+ids,page:1}).trigger('reloadGrid');
                jQuery("#list_d").jqGrid('setCaption',"Price Detail of room : "+ids)

                }
    }
    });
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{del:false,add:false,edit:false,search:false});
  jQuery("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true,searchOnEnter : false});


    jQuery("#list_d").jqGrid({
        height: 100,
    width:345,
        url:'getpricelist?q=1&id=2',
        datatype: "json",
        colNames:['from','to', 'price'],
        colModel:[
        {name:'from',index:'from', width:100},
        {name:'to',index:'to', width:100},
        {name:'price',index:'price', width:80, align:"right"},
        ],
        rowNum:5,
        rowList:[5,10,20],
        pager: '#pager_d',
        sortname: 'item',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "asc",
        multiselect: false,
        caption:"Price Detail"
    }).navGrid('#pager_d',{add:false,edit:false,del:false});

        }); 

    </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <table id="list"><tr><td></td></tr></table> 
        <div id="pager"></div> 

        <table id="list_d"></table>
        <div id="pager_d"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime


class room_type(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 40 )
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    english_title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    capacity = models.IntegerField()
    extra_capacity = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'room_types'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%d' % (self.id)


class room_icon(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    status  =  models.IntegerField()
    color_of_icon =  models.CharField(max_length=40)
    path_of_icon  =  models.CharField(max_length=255)

    #foreign_key : a room has only one icon
    rt_id = models.ForeignKey(room_type)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'room_icons'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%d' % (self.id)


class attachment(models.Model):

    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    path_of_pic = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    #foreign key : a room has many images
    rt_id = models.ForeignKey(room_type)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'attachments'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%d' % (self.id)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import simplejson
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rooms.models import *
from django.db.models import Q
from django.core import serializers


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def getdata(request):
    data=room_type.objects.all()
    json=[]
    for o in data:
        json.append({'id':o.id, 'name':o.name, 'english_title':o.english_title, 'capacity':o.capacity})

    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(json), mimetype='application/json',content_type='application/json' )


def getpricelist(request):

    requested_room_id = request.GET.get('id', '')

    room = room_type.objects.get(id = requested_room_id)
    price_list_set = room.price_list_set.all()

    json=[]
    for price_list in price_list_set:
        json.append({'from':price_list.from_date, 'to':price_list.to_date, 'price':price_list.price})


    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(json), mimetype='application/json',content_type='application/json' )

    class price_list(models.Model):

        id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
        from_date = models.CharField(max_length=10)
        to_date   = models.CharField(max_length=10)
        price = models.IntegerField()
        #foreign key : a room has a pricee list
        rt_id = models.ForeignKey(room_type)
        class Meta:
            db_table = 'price_lists'
        def __unicode__(self):
            return u'%d' % (self.id)
```

**Final Edit :**
if I've edited the html file , and now all the files are correct , if you need django source code for jqGrid examples(toolbar search , advanced master detail , and load json data) you can use mine , just work fine ;) !! 
Tnx again @Oleg for great help ;)

Comment: Post your code here instead of providing a github url. Your github repo might no longer be there tomorrow, but this question is forever. So it's important that this question contains all relevant code and is complete in itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not Django developer, but the server side code looks like it returns the array of *all* unsorted items. In the case you should use `loadonce: true` option of jqGrid. In the case jqGrid saves all data in internal parameters `data` and `_index` and change `datatype` option to `"local"` after the first load. After that the searching works **on the client side** and you don't need to make any changes in the server code.

If you use `loadonce: true` option and you need reload the data *from the server* (for example after changing `url`) then you have to reset `datatype` to its original value `datatype: "json"`:

```js
$("#list_d").jqGrid("setGridParam", {
    url: "getpricelist?q=1&id=" + encodeURIComponent(ids),
    page: 1,
    datatype: "json"
}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

I would recommend to consider to use additionally `datatype: "local"` in the second (details grid). The current code use `url:'getpricelist?q=1&id=2', datatype: "json"`. So the second grid will be filled before a row in the first grid selected. Using `datatype: "local"` prevents the loading.

I recommend you to use `gridview: true` and `autoencode: true` options in the both grids and to add `key: true` property to the definition of `"id"` column in the first grid. If you do this then `id` of `<tr>` elements (the rows of the grid) will be assign to the values from `id` column. It can simplify editing operations.

The last remark: jqGrid assign **always** `id` attribute (known as rowid) to every row of the grids. `id` have to be unique over the whole page. If you have more as one grid you could have id conflicts in the grids. To be sure that you don't have the problem you can consider to use different `idPrefix` parameters (for example `idPrefix: "g1_"` and `idPrefix: "g2_"`) for different grids (of for one from the grids). In the case the rowid values will be build from the `idPrefix` and the id assigned from your data (for example `id` column in the first grid). If you need to cut the prefix (for example to use it as a parameter in the URL) you can use `$.jgrid.stripPref` method. For example you can use `$.jgrid.stripPref($(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "idPrefix"), ids)` instead of `id` during building `url` of detailed grid.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help ! :) 
the problem was that i forgotten "loadonce:ture" !!